# Symfony2- Login Form appears again after logged in

Tags: php, symfony

Hi stackoverflow friends,

I have an instance that ,In symfony2 I created a security bundle (not used FOS USER BUNDLE) in which when I logged in, I try to access the login page again the login form is shown.Is there's no redirection to the default page, even if I'm actually logged in. How to prevent this login form ,after logged in.

Below is my security.yml

**UPDATED**

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login    

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/centerreg, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/customredirect, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/center/, roles: ROLE_CENTER }
        - { path: ^/client/, roles: ROLE_CLIENTADMIN }
        - { path: ^/examcenter/, roles: ROLE_EXAMCENTER }
        - { path: ^/tutor/, roles: ROLE_TUTOR }
        - { path: ^/evaluator/, roles: ROLE_EVALUATOR }
        - { path: ^/student/, roles: ROLE_STUDENT }
        - { path: ^/user/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: hi, why this solution doesnt work for me? .. i got cycle reference ... and like symfony doc login must be front of firewall ... how is solution for this? symfony 2.7.4

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Symfony won't automatically do this because login page is always accessible as indicated in `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

If you don't want authenticated users to get to the login page, you need to manually redirect them away from login page. To do that, go to your Controller for login action and at the beginning of loginAction() function add this:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'))
    {
        // redirect authenticated users to homepage
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_homepage'));
    }

    //other code goes here...
}
```

This will redirect authenticated users to your homepage. Of course, replace '_homepage' to route name of a page you wish to redirect users to.

Comment: Thanks Kosta...You figure out my problem.

Comment: just use $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker') instead (new in 2.6)

Answer (score 1):

can you update question with your routes?

I think you should have default path (for example, `/secure-area`) that requires authentication and some other (for example, `/secure-area/login`) that represents your login form. So, basically, returning visitor would **not** visit `/secure-area/login` but `/secure-area` instead. This way it would not show login for but reload user from session...

Comment: hi jperovic Thanks for your great response. I couldn't understand fully what you are trying to convey. I updated my question with security.yml.