# Don't show FOSUserBundle login form

Tags: php, symfony

I want to redirect people connected to a specific page when they are logged in and tried to access to FOSUserBundle login form.
Actually I'm logged in and redirected to admin dashboard but when I try to access to login form, I have access.
I tried this :

```
{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
{{ render(controller("AppBundle:Backend/Admin:index")) }}
{% endif %}
```

I don't want to show login form when I'm logged in.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your configuration ? Anything related to routes, firewalls etc. Otherwise there's not enough information to figure out what the problem is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I thik, you need to check if logged user don't have `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` role, or you can use another role for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- add an event listener that listens to the request checks the route you are on and if you are logged in (some injected services required) and if you are trying to go to the login page while logged in sets the Response of the event to a redirect response to dashboard. (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html)
- do the same logic as above in the controller. (see this similar question [Symfony2- Login Form appears again after logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824126/symfony2-login-form-appears-again-after-logged-in))